# Why table right borders are missing for new lines in Latex

Tags: tables, margins, texshop

I am using below code,

```
\begin{table}
\caption{RFID Operating Frequency}
\label{tab:2_3}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}| }
    \hline
    \Centering \textbf{Frequency Band} & \Centering  \textbf{Read Distance} & \Centering  \textbf{Data Speed} & \Centering  \textbf{Application}  \\ \hline
        \Centering Low Frequency \\ (120–150 kHz) & Hours & Days & Years \\ \hline
        \Centering High Frequency \\ (13.56 MHz) & Very complex & Complex & Simple \\ \hline
        \Centering Ultra-High Frequency \\ (868-928 MHz) & QPSK & FSK, GMSK & BPSK, O- QPSK \\ \hline
        \Centering Microwave \\ (2.45-5.8 GHz) & Microwave & Microwave & Microwave \\ \hline 

     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

Getting output where for some of the new lines table margins are missing at the rights,

[image]

**How can I fix the table margin for new lines?**

Comment: Even when the cells contain nothing, you have to add  the three `&`.

Comment: @Bernard all cells have values in my example. You mean I cant use `\\\` at the mid?

Comment: After Low frequency, High Frequency, and  the like?

Comment: No they do not, you have `Low Frequency \\ ` so ending the row there, you want `Low Frequency  &&&\\ ` so all the cells in that row are present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `makecell`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{RFID Operating Frequency}
\label{tab:2_3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
    \hline
     \thead{Frequency Band} &  \thead{Read Distance} &   \thead{Data Speed} &  \thead{Application}  \\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]{Low Frequency \\ (120–150 kHz)} & Hours & Days & Years \\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]{High Frequency \\  (13.56 MHz)} & Very complex & Complex & Simple \\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]{Ultra-High Frequency \\ (868-928 MHz)} & QPSK & FSK, GMSK & BPSK, O- QPSK \\ \hline
         \makecell[ct]{Microwave\\  (2.45-5.8 GHz)} & Microwave & Microwave & Microwave \\ \hline 

     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot leandriis. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

I would redesign your table in the following:

[image]

i.e.: I would not use vertical lines at all!

In MWE are used packages `caption` (for table caption), `booktabs` for horizontal rules in table), `makecell` for `\thead`, `makecell` command for cells formatting and `\makegapredcell` macro for inserting additional vertical space in rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{RFID Operating Frequency}
\label{tab:2_3}
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c *{3}{l} @{} }
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Frequency Band} & \thead[l]{Read Distance} & \thead[l]{Data Speed} & \thead[l]{Application}  \\
    \midrule
\makecell{Low Frequency \\ (\SIrange{120}{150}{kHz})}
    & Hours         & Days      & Years                 \\
\makecell{High Frequency \\ (\SI{13.56}{MHz})}
    & Very complex  & Complex   & Simple               \\
\makecell{Ultra-High Frequency \\ (\SIrange{868}{928}{MHz})}
    & QPSK          & FSK, GMSK & BPSK, O- QPSK         \\
\makecell{Microwave \\ (\SIrange{2.45}{5.8}{GHz})}
    & Microwave     & Microwave & Microwave             \\
    \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good advice, but "don't do that" is not an answer ;-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, sorry, but in above mine answer I didn't advice "don't do that "  nowhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` instead of the standard `{tabular}`, the vertical rules are not broken, even in the incomplete rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{RFID Operating Frequency}
\label{tab:2_3}
\centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}| }
    \hline
    \Centering \textbf{Frequency Band} & \Centering  \textbf{Read Distance} & \Centering  \textbf{Data Speed} & \Centering  \textbf{Application}  \\ \hline
        \Centering Low Frequency \\ (120–150 kHz) & Hours & Days & Years \\ \hline
        \Centering High Frequency \\ (13.56 MHz) & Very complex & Complex & Simple \\ \hline
        \Centering Ultra-High Frequency \\ (868-928 MHz) & QPSK & FSK, GMSK & BPSK, O- QPSK \\ \hline
        \Centering Microwave \\ (2.45-5.8 GHz) & Microwave & Microwave & Microwave \\ \hline 

   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, the output expected by the OP is probably more like the following code (with the tools of `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{RFID Operating Frequency}
\label{tab:2_3}
\centering
  \begin{NiceTabular}{clll}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
        \RowStyle{\bfseries}
        Frequency Band & \Block[c]{}{Read Distance} & \Block[c]{}{Data Speed} & \Block[c]{}{Application}  \\ 
        \Block{}{Low Frequency \\ (120–150 kHz)} & Hours & Days & Years \\ 
        \Block{}{High Frequency \\ (13.56 MHz)} & Very complex & Complex & Simple \\ 
        \Block{}{Ultra-High Frequency \\ (868-928 MHz)} & QPSK & FSK, GMSK & BPSK, O- QPSK \\ 
        \Block{}{Microwave \\ (2.45-5.8 GHz)} & Microwave & Microwave & Microwave \\  
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]